# Getting current browser url using selenium and python and save it

Tags: python, selenium

Using selenium and python. I am trying to get a URL and save it by doing this:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://google.com")

elem = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/a")
elem.click()

url = driver.current_url
print url
```

url that prints is google.com and not the new clicked link which gmail.
My question is, how can I get the second url and save it.

Comment: Try to make a pause, to give page some time to load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the current url before the new page is loaded. Add an [Explicit Wait](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits) to, for instance, wait for the page title to contain "Gmail":

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://google.com")

# click "Gmail" link
elem = driver.find_element_by_link_text("Gmail")
elem.click()

# wait for the page to load
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.title_contains("Gmail"))

url = driver.current_url
print(url)
```

Also note how I've improved the way to locate the `Gmail` link.